# input_report_abs axis offset

Tags: touchscreen

while setting touchscreen to xserver (as input device), it seems that after few motion, `input_report_abs()` use offset axises for X and Y, so setting (even manually) X to 0 by

```
 input_report_abs(d->idev, ABS_X, 0);
```

put the cursor at a different pixel on the screen every time.
It's not happening right at the beginning, just after some touchscreen motion (with finger).

Am I missing something about `input_report_abs`? Can the axis get changes while working for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake

input_sync() before each sections of report_abs() solved it.

I did it at first only after the report fonctions, what lead to worng parameters